# What song is this in the "Justice League" Season 2 episode "Only a Dream"?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, music-identification

There’s a song I want to identify in *Justice League* season 2 part 2 “Only a Dream”.
You can listen to the song at 0'33 and 2'34:

I checked their OST and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batman is humming *Frère Jacques*, a French lullaby. It's not obvious from the timestamps you linked (because there's background OST as well), but you can hear Doctor Destiny humming it (faintly) at 4'16 in your video.

Batman's <s>wisea**ery</s> sarcasm is that the song is about a monk not waking up early enough to ring the church's bells.

Comment: Thanks man, but im not sure what you mean by "wisea**ery"

Comment: @Binod well, Doctor Destiny attacks through dreams. Dreams typically happen when you sleep, and Batman's being a wiseass by keeping the baddie away with a song about someone who _shouldn't_ be sleeping.

Comment: It was censored, it was wisea**cry, I think. Now you may be able to discern what that means